# "They're going about it (in) the wrong way"

Tags: prepositions

What is the difference in the meanings between

> They're going about it the wrong way.

and

> They're going about it `IN` the wrong way.

Comment: Including ***in*** makes it an *explicitly* preposition-based adverbial phrase. But in relaxed conversational contexts it's quite natural to omit the preposition. Compare your (optionally) preposition based usage with the single-word versions: *You're doing it **wrongly*** ("true adverb") and  *You're doing it **wrong*** ("flat adverb").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning. Any difference is that including 'in' is maybe slightly more formal. When speaking informally, people often omit words that are not necessary, and the 'in' is one of these.